# Clean URLs from pages in a custom Jekyll folder

Tags: yaml, jekyll, permalinks

I'm building a Jekyll site made of static pages (e.g. nothing in the `_posts` directory), and rather than keeping each page in the root directory, I'd like to keep it in a custom `pages` directory (for organization's sake).

However, I don't want this structure reflected in my URLs, so in my `_config.yml` I have:

`permalink: /:title`

With this configuration, my desired URL would be `site.com/pagename`, but I don't get a rendered page unless I hit `site.com/pages/pagename.html`.

Could anyone help me configure my build to achieve the former? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are static pages so the entry in `_config.yml` is going to be ignored.

From the sounds of it you will need to create a URL rewrite rule. How to do this will depend on the web server that is servering up the pages.

Comment: This is the route I ended up going. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding YAML Front Matter to these static pages? For example:

```
---
title: "pagetitle"
---
```

This way, Jekyll should recognize it as a `Page` (instead of a `StaticPage`) and would use your permalink configuration.

Comment: Yep, I did this, but still no dice.